# Is there any way to force SQL Server to use samples of recent data in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

As I understand SQL Server estimates cardinality based off of samples of table data. We have a daily payments reconciliation report that is intermittently generating a bad execution plan.

From what I can tell this is due in part from bad cardinality estimates in the plans. I'm wondering if there is a way to force a query to generate the samples it uses to make cardinality estimates with a bias towards more recently inserted / updated rows or higher numeric primary keys (aka more recent).

If there is a way to do this at the table level or database level I would also be interested in that as well.

Comment: Use options to guide SQL Server into generating the best plan.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/option-clause-transact-sql

Comment: Are the index statistics out-of-date?

Comment: We have been updating the stats and recompiling the query quite frequently and are still receiving timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at "Parameter Sniffing" and the `OPTIMIZE FOR` feature in SQL. It allows you to tweak the way SQL generates a query plan for re-used, variable code (views, TVFs, etc.):

```
SELECT *
FROM ImportLog
WHERE StateCode = @StateCode
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR (@StateCode = 'CA'));
```